# ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Trying to setup a simple web application scheduler. So here is my configuration:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>hello.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

My classes look like below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class);
}
public void onStartup(ServletContext arg0) throws ServletException {

        SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class);

    }

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.setPort(8081);
        factory.setSessionTimeout(50, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        return factory;
    }
}
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("Testing successful ");
    }
}
```

But when i try to start the container i see the exception

```
ERROR 2592 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
...
...
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:174)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:147)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
        ... 20 more
```

I tried to follow [Spring Boot Testing: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095189/spring-boot-testing-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missin) but in vain.

Kindly suggest, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only running `ScheduledTasks`:

```
SpringApplication.run(ScheduledTasks.class);
```

when you should run:

```
SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
```

Running ScheduledTasks means that Spring Boot doesn't know about the configuration in `Application`. Crucially, it means that it doesn't see `@EnableAutoConfiguration` which is what switches on auto-configuration and, because you have Tomcat on the classpath, creates the embedded Tomcat instance.

I would fix this by moving the `@EnableScheduling` annotation from `ScheduledTasks` to `Application`, running `Application.class` rather than `ScheduledTasks.class`, and annotating `ScheduledTasks` with `@Component`:

**Application.class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableScheduling
public class Application implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    // …
}
```

**ScheduledTasks.class**:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 500)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        System.out.println("Testing successful ");
    }
}
```

Moving `@EnableScheduling` means that its on a configuration class, where it belongs. Running `Application.class` means that Spring Boot sees all of its configuration, including enabling component scanning and enabling auto-configuration. Annotating `ScheduledTasks` with `@Component` means that it's found by component scanning and its `@Scheduled` method is detected.

This should get things up and running. I would also correct your pom so that you're not using a mixture of versions of Spring Boot (you have 1.1.6 and 1.1.7 in there at the moment) and get rid of your `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean in favour of configuring the port and session timeout using `application.properties` in `src/main/resources` instead:

**application.properties:**

```
server.port = 8081
server.session-timeout = 3000
```

Comment: I want this application to run from within a tomcat so how can i inject tomcat instance rather than a EmbeddedInstance. I did as you suggested but still i see the same exception. But atleast it is able to load the spring context now.

Comment: If you're deploying your application to a standalone Tomcat instance then you'll need to configure the port in Tomcat's server.xml rather than via application.properties or your own EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.

Comment: yes i have configured my tomcat for 8080 and am able to access normal webapps on that port and am not using any properties files. The issue i see is since most of the applications on web talk about embedded container the web module configuration is not proper i think. As i previously said the webapp is trying to spring boot but failing because TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory is missing. How can i let the webapp know that its available but not within it but its external to it.

Comment: Also a strange thing is when tomcat starts i see spring-boot version as 1.1.9 where as i am using 1.1.7

Comment: You should extend SpringBootServletInitializer and override configure rather than implementing WebApplicationInitializer

Comment: "Whitelabel Error Page
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available"
configure() is overridden to return application.sources(Application.class); and i see no other error message

Answer (score 0):

besides what @Andy Wilkinson pointed out which is true in the OP's case but not in mine

I saw that my spring-boot-starter-tomcat was with

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

( as i was adding a servlet initializer to run it on wildfly) i commented out that bit and removed provided from spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency and it started working. Adding here just in case some one else has the same issue

Answer (score 0):

My one got fixed using this **dependency** :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```