# Spring boot -- Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, frameworks, spring-boot

**Spring Boot**

I was trying to running my spring Boot application in intelliJ but getting an Error:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-26 23:09:30.883  INFO 3960 --- [           main] com.example.he.ExampleApplication         : Starting ExampleApplication on user with PID 3960 (F:\WORK\Work_Project\Example_Application-master\Example_Application-master\build\classes\main started by user in F:\WORK\Work_Project\Example_Application-master\Example_Application-master)
2016-01-26 23:09:30.892  INFO 3960 --- [           main] com.example.he.ExampleApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-26 23:09:31.042  INFO 3960 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@73d4cc9e: startup date [Tue Jan 26 23:09:31 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-26 23:09:31.242  WARN 3960 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
2016-01-26 23:09:31.453 ERROR 3960 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.he.ExampleApplication.main(ExampleApplication.java:15) [main/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:185) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 13 common frames omitted

2016-01-26 23:09:31.456  INFO 3960 --- 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Iam using Gradle.This is my **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'Example-Application'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.30')
        compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    compile('javax.servlet:jstl:1.2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

This is the configuration class:

```
package com.example.he.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/city").setViewName("city");
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("city");
    registry.addViewController("/userAdd").setViewName("user");
    registry.addViewController("/created").setViewName("created");
    registry.addViewController("/createblog").setViewName("blog");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");

  }

}
```

And this is my Application class:

```
package com.example.he;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication.class, args);
    }


  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ExampleApplication.class);
  }


}
```

and also i have tried these annotations as well.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
```

I am new to spring and i don't really understand what these annotations do.I tried following some of these but couldn't fix the issue.

[Spring Boot: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783391/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-embedd)

[Spring Boot Testing: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24095189/spring-boot-testing-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missin)

I tried building the application using console(gradle build), build is successful but running the **war** gives me an error: **Unable to start embedded Tomcat** . Could someone please help me ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get your application up and running. The only change I made to get it running was to comment out a couple of your dependencies in your build.gradle file.

In the dependencies block below, 3 lines are commented out. The spring-boot-start-jpa line I commented out only because I did not have a configured dataSource.

However, if you only comment out the servlet-api and jstl dependencies, your app should start without issue, it did for me.

```
dependencies {
    //compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.30')
    //compile('javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5')
    //compile('javax.servlet:jstl:1.2')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: but why does that fix it?

Comment: Because the correct version of those dependencies (servlet, jstl) are automatically added by spring boot as part of auto-configuring a web application.

Answer (score 12):

I also have this error and it only happens with Intellij. Finally I got it working by commenting out this:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It did take me lots of time figuring this out. Hope this helps those who encountering the similar error.

Comment: worked for me only after commenting out following `<scope>provided</scope>` from above dependency. It's because the way intelliJ or eclipse handles transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I missed to add this in **pom.xml**

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding annotation on main boot application class worked for me.
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ExampleApplication{.....

Answer (score 1):

Atleast in my case, this was a Intellij specific issue, as the Boot-app worked just fine when running Eclipse/VSCode.

I started getting this issue post the new Intellij update 2020 CE. This was apparently solved after selecting dependencies with provided scope option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning the `C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository` and then reimporting all maven dependencies worked for me. I also deleted all overriding dependencies in my pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration` solved my issue. But my only doubt is `@SpringBootApplication` should internally add `@EnableAutoconfiguration`. This is as per spring web site https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Not sure what to believe...It took 8 hours to find out this.