# Geeting error : Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

Getting Error while running springboot application

```
Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
```

I have tried solution provided in below link

[Spring boot -- Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021328/spring-boot-unable-to-start-embeddedwebapplicationcontext-due-to-missing-embe)

This is my pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- spark launcher -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-launcher_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis Dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Tomcat Embed -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Json -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

And below is the main 
:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.howtodoinjava.app")
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Below is the controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    private SparkRepo sparkRepo;

    public IndexController(SparkRepo sparkRepo) {
        this.sparkRepo = sparkRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, path = "/appLaunch")
    public String getData(Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int status = sparkRepo.sparkJobStatus();
        model.addAttribute("status", status);
        return "recommendation";
    }
    // ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("recommendation");

}
```

and below is the implementation:

```
@Repository
public class SparkImpl implements SparkRepo {

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public int sparkJobStatus() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process spark = new SparkLauncher().setAppResource("/my/app.jar")
                .setMainClass("my.spark.app.Main")
                .setMaster("local")
                .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
                .launch();

        return spark.waitFor();
    }
}
```

And this the the error I am getting after running

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:536) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.howtodoinjava.app.SpringBootWebApplication.main(SpringBootWebApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:189) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

I am new to springboot, and also treid different scenario line adding scope to tomcat, removing it.
But still getting the error:

Comment: is that all the stacktrace?

Comment: yes, this is complete error stacktrace